# Wrapping a C++ class in Python using SWIG

Tags: c++, python, swig

**example.h**:

```
#ifndef EXAMPLE_H
#define EXAMPLE_H

class Math {
 public:
    int pi() const;
    void pi(int pi);
 private:
    int _pi;
};

#endif
```

**example.cpp**:

```
#include "example.h"

int Math::pi() const {
    return this->_pi;
}  
void Math::pi(int pi) {
    this->_pi = pi;
}
```

**example.swig**:

```
%module example
%{ 
    #define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
    #include "example.h"
%}
%include "example.h"
```

I then generate the wrappers, "example.py" and "example_wrap.c" using:

```
swig  -python example.swig
```

When I try to compile the wrapper class using:

```
g++ -fPIC -c example.cpp example_wrap.c -I/usr/local/include/python2.6/
```

I get the following error:

```
example_wrap.cpp: In function "PyObject* Swig_var_Math_get()":
example_wrap.cpp:2725: error: expected primary-expression before "void"
example_wrap.cpp:2725: error: expected ")" before "void"
```

The Error is at the following line :

```
pyobj = SWIG_NewPointerObj(SWIG_as_voidptr(&Math), SWIGTYPE_p_class,  0 );

#define SWIG_as_voidptr(a) (void *)((const void *)(a))
```

Is it the right way to generate the wrapper class "example_wrap.c"?

Comment: You've got pretty bad formatting issues.

Comment: Not that bad, they just didn't know to indent all the code four spaces.  Fixed.

Answer (score 13):

I think the swig command should be "swig -c++ -python example.swig"

Answer (score 5):

There's not enough information here to be sure what's wrong, but I have two ideas for things you can try.

1. Your `g++` invocation is compiling a C source file as if it were C++.  This is *not* guaranteed to work.  Try instead

   ```
   gcc -I/usr/local/include/python2.6 -fPIC -c example_wrap.c
   gcc -I/usr/local/include/python2.6 -fPIC -c example.cpp
   g++ -shared example_wrap.o example.o -o example.so
   ```

   (yes, srsly, only use g++ for the link)
2. If that doesn't work, compile `example_wrap.c` like this:

   ```
   gcc -I/usr/local/include/python2.6 -fPIC -c -save-temps example_wrap.c
   ```

That will fail the same way but will produce a file named `example_wrap.i` which is the result of preprocesing.  It will be gigantic.  Search that file for the function `Swig_var_Math_get`, and add to your question the *complete text* of that function (but nothing else).

Comment: Oops, example.cpp should be compiled with g++. Why gcc? Avoid C++ mangling?

Comment: It is only necessary to use `g++` to link. `gcc -c` does the Right Thing when applied to a `.cpp` source file. But `g++ -c` does *not* do the Right Thing when applied to a `.c` source file. So the easiest rule to remember is, always use `gcc` to compile, even if the source is C++; only use `g++` to link a program that contains C++. Same same for any of the other languages supported by GCC: use the language-specific driver only to link.  Personally I don't think the language-specific drivers should even exist, but they do let you not have to know exactly how to call for the runtime libraries.

Comment: well, yes, you can use gcc to compile C++. You could also use gcc to link C++, but you'd have to manually link against libstdc++, etc. Put that way, I find easier to use gcc for C, and g++ for C++. But it's just personal taste. The important is that problem & solution were correctly pointed out. +1

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your replies!

The `-c++` option is better to generate the actual C++ class for the wrapper (`-v` stands for *verbose* mode):

```
swig -c++ -v -python example.swig
```

I then used g++ to compile the wrapper:

```
g++ -fPIC -c example.cpp example_wrap.cxx -I/usr/local/include/python2.6/
```

And the following command to build the shared object. Of course, you might need to remove the superfluous includes (`-I`) and libraries (`-L`). The important flags are `-shared` and `-fPIC`.

```
g++ example_wrap.o example.o -L/u01/app/oracle/product/1020.full/lib  -I/usr/local/ssl/include  -L/usr/local/ssl/lib -lclntsh -lssl -lcrypto -ldl -L/usr/local/lib -L/lib64 -L/usr/local/lib/python2.6/ -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lboost_thread -lboost_date_time -lglog -lmodpbase64 -lpthread -ldl -lrt -shared -fPIC -o _example.so
```

Comment: Shouldn't this one be marked as the *accepted answer*?