# Python wrapper for C++ using SWIG

Tags: python, c++, gcc, static-libraries, swig

I'm going to write a python wrapper for some c++ code using ***SWIG***. The main class is `Cryptographer` which uses two ***static*** libraries that are **[libgmp.a](https://gmplib.org/)** and **[libgmpxx.a](https://gmplib.org/)**. So my codes are like this (some implementation codes are removed for simplicity) :

**example.h:**

```
/* example.h */
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include "gmp.h"
#include "gmpxx.h"

using namespace std;

class Cryptographer {
    private:
        mpz_class num;
    public:
        Cryptographer();
        virtual ~Cryptographer();
};
```

**example.cpp:**

```
/* example.cpp */
#include "example.h"

Cryptographer::Cryptographer() {
    num = 12;
}

Cryptographer::~Cryptographer() {
}
```

For the two files above, created a SWIG interface:

**example.i:**

```
%module example
%{ 
    #define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
    #include "example.h"
%}
%include "example.h"
```

Then i run these commands : (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4596585/5199226))

```
swig -c++ -python example.i // creates "example_wrap.cxx"

gcc -c -fPIC example_wrap.cxx -I/usr/include/python2.7 // outputs "example_wrap.o"

gcc -c -fPIC example.cpp -I/usr/include/python2.7 // creates "example.o"

g++ -shared example_wrap.o example.o -o example.so // creates "example.so"
```

Then i try to import the `example` module inside python2.7 but unfortunately it doesn't work:

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import example
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: ./example.so: undefined symbol: __gmpz_set_si
```

I guess that is something is wrong with those **libgmp** and **libgmpxx** libraries that are not linked correctly during linking process but i have no idea how to fix it.

**BTW, all needed files can be accessed by [this link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1prN8HxUSZZwSjMKnP6tZVouaTnuXmtLq).**

Comment: Can you provide gcc version?

Comment: @p-a-o-l-o here you go : *gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine in gcc 6.3.0:

```
g++ -shared -o _example.so example_wrap.o example.o libgmp.a libgmpxx.a
```

You may need to provide the full path to the `.a` files, though.

And those libraries need a position independent code (aka -fPIC) compilation.

To rebuild the libraries: 
1) download this: https://gmplib.org/download/gmp/gmp-6.1.2.tar.bz2
2) extract the files in a directory of choice.
3) From that very directory, run this command:

```
./configure --with-pic=yes --enable-cxx
```

If everything goes fine, you will have a `Makefile`. 
So call `make`, and `make install`, right after. Done.

Comment: And you could import `example` module inside python without any errors? i tested the command but for me it gives error : `/usr/bin/ld: libgmp.a(memory.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against .rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
libgmp.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: Actually it gave "ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (initexample)", but I get rid of it rebuilding the library as _example.so. The linker issue has gone, I updated the answer to clarify your relocation problem.

Comment: And this time you could import the module inside python? Please add the commands for rebuilding those two libraries to the post so i can follow what you have done, thanks a lot.

Comment: Updated. Good luck.

Comment: Wow it's now working perfect. I know i would face the error: "ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (initexample)" but you solved the problem in advance, many many thanks man.